# How to land a job

Tags: job-search

I am wondering as an IT student soon graduating how to land a job on the field of study? I have send multiple applications and hone my LinkedIn to the max. Still I get an answer that I am required to have 5 years experience on the field. How to get experience if no one hires? Any tips from you experts would be greatly appriciated

Comment: Look for graduate roles, specifically targeting people fresh out of their degree courses.

Comment: Entire books and websites are dedicated to this topic. It's too broad for this site. One free tip: don't ever use phrases like "hone to the max".

Comment: Have you considered networking where you go to events and talk to people directly about possible positions? It has worked for me at times. Also, have you gone through every LinkedIn group that could post jobs in your field near you?

Comment: Your educational institution should have a placement office.. They will know of the entry level positions.

Comment: Hey, you're not an "IT student", you're an _engineer_.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a good resource available at wherever you are studying, they know the local conditions and often have contacts in the industry that can help get entry level work.

At the very least they should have locale specific information better than you would get here.